# get value from json api flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api

I have an API and get the data from them.

Actually, I want to change the box color if any string exists in query.

Currently, I check if the last one is.

The code I use:

```
 border: Border(
                  left: BorderSide(
                      color: model.data[model.data.length - 1].desc ==
                              'DONE'
                          ? greenColor
                          : redColor,
                      width: 3.0)),
```

The border is green only if the `DONE` word exist in last value in query, but if exist but not in last the border is red.
In certain cases it can be in the penultimate place or somewhere in the middle. It is not always the last. To check if the word `DONE` exists in JSON query regardless of where it is in the sequence.

The JSON:

```
[
   {
      "id":"123",
      "title":"Alpha",
      "desc":"NEW"
   },
   {
      "id":"123",
      "title":"Alpha",
      "desc":"DONE"
   },
   {
      "id":"123",
      "title":"Alpha",
      "desc":"IN PROGRESS"
   }
]
```

Did you need more info to give me a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- indexWhere can solve it
- example

```
 model.data.indexWhere((m) => m.desc == 'DONE')? greenColor : redColor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this many ways

```
Color borderColor = Colors.red;

//1st way 
final index = model.data.indexWhere((element) => element.desc == "DONE"); // Return -1 If 'DONE' is not found
debugPrint("index of Done $index"); 
borderColor = index != -1 ? Colors.green : Colors.red;

//2nd way 
final isDone = model.data.map((e) => e.desc == "DONE").toList().isNotEmpty; // Return false If 'DONE' is not found
debugPrint("If Done exists $isDone");
borderColor = isDone ? Colors.green : Colors.red;

Put line in your code
```

> model.data.indexWhere((element) => element.desc == "DONE") ?
> greenColor : redColor

Comment: Thanks, but this is not i'm looking for. I have model and read from them.

Comment: you can also try with your model too.

Comment: answer updated you can use above functions with models too.

Comment: array functions in dart & how it's works, for better understanding refer this link-https://codeburst.io/top-10-array-utility-methods-you-should-know-dart-feb2648ee3a2